# when I have to do setNeedDisplay or setNeedLayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

When I do something on UIKit, I really want to ask a question.

when do I have to call `setNeedsDisplay` and when `setNeedLayout`?

Comment: Is this difficult to understand by reading the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `setNeedDisplay` forces the iOS to redraw. `setNeedLayout` forces `layoutSubviews` method to be called before next redraw.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Apple Documentation for this.

[`setNeedsLayout`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW28) **will layout subviews**

> Call this method on your application’s main thread when you want to adjust the layout of a view’s subviews.

[`setNeedsDisplay`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCCADHC) **will call for a redraw of your view (drawRect:, etc)**.

> You can use this method or the setNeedsDisplayInRect: to notify the system that your view’s contents need to be redrawn.

Answer (score -1):

In simple terms

setNeedsDisplay : To redraw your view
setNeedsLayout : To adjust positioning/sizing of your view